# Anyone have any luck exposing Ubercart's "enter your VAT" part of the form?

Tags: ubercart

I am using http://drupal.org/project/uc_vat and http://drupal.org/project/uc_vat_number and am able to enter different VAT rates, but a the moment it seems that it simply applies whatever is the last item in the list as VAT. I need to find where in the interface (I may be being blind as well as ignorant) it will allow me to enable the part of the form where the user can select that they have a VAT number to enter to avoid paying VAT. I am pretty sure it is part of the interface, I just don't know where to find it.

If I find it, I will post and/or close the question. Many thanks for any and all support!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This module is dependant on the billable address module being enabled. I did not need the billable module and thus is did not show (javascript dependancy).